# How to replace values of different columns with the column name for many columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
foo = pd.DataFrame({'prod_a': [np.nan, 'yes', 'no'], 'id': [1,2,3],
                    'prod_b': ['no', 'yes', 'yes']})
```

I would like to replace for all the `prod_` the `yes`'s with the respective column name and the `no`'s with `''`

My result dataframe looks like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'prod_a': [np.nan, 'prod_a', ''], 'id': [1,2,3],
                        'prod_b': ['', 'prod_b', 'prod_b']})
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `np.select`:

```
foo[:] = np.select((foo.eq('yes'), foo.eq('no')),  # the conditions
                   (foo.columns,   ''),            # the replacements
                   foo)                            # the default
```

Output:

```
   prod_a  id  prod_b
0     NaN   1        
1  prod_a   2  prod_b
2           3  prod_b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
foo = pd.DataFrame({'prod_a': [np.nan, 'yes', 'no'], 'id': [1,2,3],
                'prod_b': ['no', 'yes', 'yes']})

foo=foo.replace(['no'],"")
print(foo)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.